# Where to download GWT4NB?

Tags: java, gwt, plugins, netbeans

So what might end up being the most stupid question of the day, where exactly can I download the GWT Plugin for Netbeans? I've been googling, most URLs that I find I think are outdated and give me a 404.

The one that I did found however, I believe to be the right page/site but I can for the life of me not find the link that actually lets you **download the plugin**.

Thanks in advance, and again, I did Google. 
Sorry for the inconvenience,

This is the link I found:
http://java.net/projects/gwt4nb/pages/Home

Comment: http://java.net/projects/gwt4nb/downloads ?

Comment: How did you find that??? That's embarrassing..

Comment: Follow the link you provided, on the left side there is section called "Project Features". There are some menu items, the second one is called "Downloads". Yes, this is embarrassing ;]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is
See if this helps

http://java.net/projects/gwt4nb/downloads