# Can't Install GWT4NB Plugin in Netbeans 7.1

Tags: java, gwt, plugins, netbeans

I downloaded the GWT4NB(Google Web Toolkit for Netbeans) plugin and tried intstalling it, but what happened was that I got this error message stating:

> Some plugins require plugin Java Hints to be installed.
>   The plugin Java Hints is requested in implementation version 11.

And then I have to cancel the installation since it's looking for dependencies or something I susspect. The version of the GWT4NB is 2.10.6 and of course my Netbeans is version 7.1.

I understand that it might work with an older version of netbeans but my current version is set up perfectly and for me to go and re-install all my other plugins and configurations would be way to cumbersome to do. GWT4NB is supposed to work with Netbeans 7.1, or so they claim.

Thanks in advance for any help!

PS - Here's the link to that plugin: http://java.net/jira/secure/attachment/48362/org-netbeans-modules-gwt4nb-2.10.6.nbm

Answer (score 2):

I too faced the same problem. So i had to download Java Hints Plugin but when i started installing that, i came to know that it also has four other dependencies.

As a resolution, i downloaded

> org-netbeans-modules-gwt4nb-2.10.4.nbm

This got installed in NetBeans 7.0 and 7.1 well and i had my project working well. Hope this helps you also.

Here is the download link for my Version of GWT4NB:

https://github.com/gwt4nb/gwt4nb/wiki/Downloads

Version 2.10.4 is available at the bottom of the page.

Comment: +1 for http://java.net/projects/gwt4nb/downloads/download/ , I really couldn't find that!

Comment: you can directly click on the link. it will redirect to download page

Comment: I mean I really couldn't find this link on Google :D

Comment: hope the link works fine after http://stackoverflow.com/users/320399/b-long edited it...

Comment: It seems the project has moved around quite a bit.  I updated the link (again) to the latest location.  Another user has asked a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9224254/where-to-download-gwt4nb

Comment: Now its available with NetBeans